How can I find and display nearby toilets in my mobile school project app using Mapbox?
I recently started working on a school project using kotlin where we're building a "Find Restroom" app. I decided to use Mapbox for this because I wanted to learn how to use their API and mapping tools. However, I’ve run into a problem: I can’t seem to find a way to search for restrooms (toilets) in my proximity using Mapbox.
I tried the Mapbox Geocoding API with keywords like toilet, restroom, and WC, but I keep getting empty results (I’m testing in Slovenia, specifically Maribor). For example, here’s a sample query I tried:
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/toilet.json?proximity=15.645881,46.554650&bbox=15.58,46.50,15.73,46.60&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

Output:
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "query": ["toilet"],
   "features": [],
   "attribution": "NOTICE: © 2024 Mapbox and its suppliers..."
}

I noticed that Google Maps seems to handle this kind of search easily and shows nearby restrooms. However, I really want to stick with Mapbox for this project to learn and explore its capabilities.

Based on https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding-v5/, you need to be moving to a different API anyway in five days: "Points of Interest (POI) data will be removed from Geocoding v5 API on December 20, 2024.
If your application relies on searching for POIs like restaurants, gas stations, and landmarks, we recommend transitioning to the Search Box API."

Yes I tried using Search Box API, but there is also no option to search for toilets (there are stations, restaurants but no single toilet)
